# Python dataframe loop row by row would not change value no matter what

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change value of my panda dataframe but it just so stubborn and would not change the value desired. I have used `df.at` as suggested in some other post and it is not working as a way to change/modify data in dataframe.

```
HOUSING_PATH = "datasets/housing"
csv_path = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "property6.csv")
housing = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

headers = ['Sold Price', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Land Size', 'Total Bedrooms', 'Total Bathrooms', 'Parking Spaces']
# housing.at[114, headers[6]] = 405 and I want to change this to empty or 0 or None as 405 parking spaces does not make sense. 

for index in housing.index:
# Total parking spaces in this cell 
    row = housing.at[index, headers[6]]
# if total parking spaces is greater than 20
    if row > 20:
# change to nothing 
        row = ''

print(housing.at[114, headers[6]])
# however, this is still 405
```

Like why is this happening? Why can't I replace the value of the dataframe? They are`<class 'numpy.float64'>`, I have checked so the if statement should work and it is working. But just changing the value

Comment: Can you share some sample data and on what condition you are trying to change the values of data frame, so that the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: You are changing the variable "row" rather than the original data.

Comment: You never change the dataframe... You simply assign something to a new variable (`row`). You are not doing anything with this variable. Why do you expect the dataframe to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it like this. Once you assign the value of `housing.at[index, headers[6]]`, you create a new variable which contains this value (`row`). Then you change the new variable, not the original data.

```py
for index in housing.index:
    # if total parking spaces is greater than 20
    if housing.at[index, headers[6]] > 20:
       # Set the value of original data to empty string
       housing.at[index, headers[6]] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done without the use of `for` loop. Use `pd.loc` to filter the data frame based on condition and change the values

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import os

HOUSING_PATH = "datasets/housing"
csv_path = os.path.join(HOUSING_PATH, "property6.csv")
housing = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

housing.loc[housing["Parking Spaces"] > 20, "Parking Spaces"] = ""
```

Comment: As the exact dataset is not available, if the code raises any errors comment it down and share sample data

Answer (score 0):

There are several built-in functions to finish such tasks. (where, mask, replace etc.)

```
# Series.where(cond, other=nan, inplace=False, axis=None, level=None, errors='rais',...)
data2=data.iloc[:,6]
data2.where(data2<=20, '', inplace=True)
```